# Loop in CSS and HTML? Enlarge/popup an image upon hovering but have 1000 photos

Tags: html, css, image

Every thread that I have searched so far involves hovering over a single image, requiring one img src, which the below code can solve. However I have 1000 photos to hover over and this is extremely tedious and impractical with my current solution. I'm quite new to CSS and HTML but I essentially want to create a loop to apply this hover command over and over. If you look at the HTML my intent should be clear.

Below is the code that I have so far:

CSS:

```
.hover-title {
    display: inline-grid;
    pointer-events: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index:-1;
}

.hover-image {
    visibility: hidden;
}

body:not(.mobile) .hover-title:hover + .hover-image {
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.hover-image {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(40%, 40%);
    transform: scale(.5.5);
    z-index: -999;
    pointer-events: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

/* Change width and height to scale images */
    width: 70vw;
    height: 70vh;
}

.hover-image img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 100% !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="hover-title">{image 1 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 1}</div>

<div class="hover-title">{image 2 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 2}</div> 

<div class="hover-title">{image 3 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 3}</div> 

<div class="hover-title">{image 4 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 4}</div>

<div class="hover-title">{image 5 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 5}</div>

<div class="hover-title">{image 6 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 6}</div> 

<div class="hover-title">{image 7 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 7}</div> 

<div class="hover-title">{image 8 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 8}</div>

<div class="hover-title">{image 9 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 9}</div>

<div class="hover-title">{image 10 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 10}</div> 

<div class="hover-title">{image 10 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 10}</div> 

<div class="hover-title">{image 11 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 11}</div>

<div class="hover-title">{image 12 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 12}</div>

<div class="hover-title">{image 13 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 13}</div> 

<div class="hover-title">{image 14 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 14}</div> 

<div class="hover-title">{image 15 scale="5"}</div>
<div class="hover-image">{image 15}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not a programming language nor CSS ; so you cant have any loop in them ;
You can use Server-side language to do what you want

Comment: Yeah, I understand - that's why I'd like another work around but in principle this is my hope.

Answer (score 0):

HTML and CSS does not have loop but javascript(client side) and server side languages have it and could do it. so:

1- Using a server side language like PHP:
if you have 1000 images with titles stored in an associative array($images) with title and src keys that is fetched from database, then your loop is:

```
<?php 
/* assume $images is an array with this structure :
   $images=array(['src'=>'images/src1.jpg','title'=>'title1']
                ,['src'=>'images/src2.jpg','title'=>'title2'] 
                ... 
                );
*/
foreach($images as $img)
{
   echo '<div class="hover-title">'.$img['title'].'</div>
         <div class="hover-image">'.$img['src'].'</div>';
}
?>
```

2-if you have to do this job whitout any server side language and your problem is just making an html file, then you could use some copy paste tricks using excel and notepad++ to make this long repeated list of div and img tags.

3-if you have to do this job without any server side language and still you want to use loop, JAVASCRIPT could help you to loop on images but you should have all images srcs and titles in an object or array inside your page and then make dynamic html code at page load.

Comment: Thank you! I chose the manual method (2) using excel :)